# What is difference between Authentication and Authenticate in spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to implement Authentication for Rest API's using Spring boot but i'm getting confusion between word authentication and authenticate. Someone please help me how to implement Authentication and authenticate in spring boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Security Architecture [guide](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture):

> Application security boils down to two more or less independent problems: authentication (who are you?) and authorization (what are you allowed to do?).

As a suggestion, you can review these sample articles:

[Spring Security with JWT](https://dev.to/keysh/spring-security-with-jwt-3j76)

[Introduction to Spring Method Security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-method-security)